# Reading large amout of data from database and write it on XML

Tags: xml, jdbc, jaxb

We are creating a XML file through JAXB for data flow from one place to another, and we are getting the data from database.
Now my problem is that we have very large amount of data and we are using JDBC for database connectivity.
After some time we are getting 'Out of Memory Error'. we also increased the value memory value  for -Xms and -Xmx to maximum allowed by eclipse.
From this site got solution for setting batch size but this problem persists.
We have to create one XML for all the data which is present in the database.
Please suggest me some solution.

Thnaks in Advance.
Abhimanyu

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend marshalling to a a StAX `XMLStreamWriter`.  This way you can read a chunk of data then then use JAXB to marshal it, then do additional chunks until all of the data has been written to xML.